# Why who is aministering the power pretends to be right?

Tags: social-psychology

I apologize for my english and I would really appreciate an help at improving the question.

It's very frequent that the guy who is in charge **pretends** that he would be "right" (and the other would be wrong). This happens between parents and their children, in couples, in web forums, between teachers and scolar, in the HR, in the job, on social network groups, when speaking to police officers, judges and so on. The first one tries to explain to the others why he is right and the other is wrong.

Actually the idea itself of "beliefs", "dicotomic" helps to show why it's pretty hard to speak of being "right". 
It's enough to compare the formulation of any Evidence Based Paper to understand how subjective we are as human being. The law itself has often dicotomic formulation, the language used by lawyer is very approximative and far away from being objective. A math theorem is objective.

So why authority charged people act in this way? In social science, pretending to be right has been proved to be effective for dealing with most of people?

Comment: An example scenario would be nice. I'm not clear about how you're defining "right".

Comment: @Seanny123 When I speak with a policeman he pretends I did something wrong, something against the rules. But there are studies which shows that the laws are contradicting themself. Some Narcyssyst / Borderline / Psychopathic also thinks to be ethycal while they are instead manipulating people. Thinking to be the guy who is doing the actions better is easy to understand. But why trying to convince the others or the other guy that he is doing a wrong thing?

Comment: Narcyssists use that for manipulation inside the couple.. but what about a judge, a policeman or a moderator in a forum?

Comment: I think I'm closer to understanding this. In the case with the policeman, the policeman wants isn't being rational. He's assuming you've done something wrong and he's ignoring the fact that the law is complicated. However, he's pretending he's right, because his authority depends on this. Am I close?

Comment: @Seanny123: yes, a lot! But I also wonder if it's also an effective to way to manipulate the others. I mean maybe people slowly get aware that they are not really "right" (because it's impossible to be 100% right in a world which is complicated and far away from being dichotomic, I guess), but they go on pretending that because it makes their life easier.. I think this happens with every person who feel weak but try to show himself as being strong.. I think to borderline people as an extreme example.. but maybe I'm wrong..

Comment: So to make this an answerable question, can you imagine a type of experiment that would explain this behaviour?

Comment: @Seanny123: I am not sure I've understood the question.. to reproduce the behaviour is easy. But to make an experiment to check if people are "intentionally" manipulatory or just wanting to be rational is not easy I guess.. probably an experiment where some subjects are asked to justify their actions and other subjects are totally free to act as they whish could give an hint.. but any answer will be appreciated!